# How to send keystrokes to an inactive window

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, exe, autopilot

I'm doing the autopilot function in tanks.
I am faced with the problem of entering the W key.
What is the essence of the function, you press Q and your tank goes by itself, that is, with pressing Q, you clamp W. But if you go through another window, then W is released.
I want to make it possible to press Q and go to another window , but the W key was pressed into the game and the tank was driving.

Sorry for my English, all questions to Yandex translator)

I tried to create both a third-party exe file that is not embedded in the game, and tried to use a dll library.
in any case, when switching to another window, the W key is released
postMessage but when postMessage is performed in the game window, the game freezes.
I also tried using SendMessage, but the same thing

Comment: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513) (or SendMessage)